# How to rewrite old dojo based UI in web app to new Angular 2 framework?

Tags: javascript, angular, dojo, scada, scadalts

With UI based on dojo we have problem with multiple conflicts with other js librarys (jquery, dwr, plugins jquery).

In new UI based on Angular 2 we plan to use websockets and REST API.

Are there any contraindications to-use websockets?

How many time in your opinion will take rewriting of 45 forms with standard validation (from 5 to 20 input fields) and about 20 grids (tables) to Angular 2?

I need simple in terms of code mechanism to design custom graphics views for SCADA preferably as Angular solution (components).

Comment: Design views wants to use the https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To estimate the time needed to complete the application, you have to prepare a prototype with the following components:

- table,
- form,
- and validation.

Then you have to check the time needed to prepare the prototype. If the application has to be made from 20 editable tables, you have to multiply it by 20 and then you will receive an estimated time required to complete the project, made of a repeatable elements.

If you want more accurate estimation, you have to count the time required to complete the random 3 tables and multiply it by 7.

In case, when there are a severe restrictions or cash penalties about the project closure delay, you can multiply the estimated time by 3, just to make sure you won't exceed the deadline.